# Docker как установить webonyx/graphql-php

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer

Я пытаюсь развернуть приложение на graphQL, для этого я хочу установить расширение `docker-php-ext-install`, но при выполнении команды `docker-compose build` - получаю ошибку:

```html
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install     pdo_mysql     && a2enmod     rewrite     && webonyx/graphql-php]: exit code: 127
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

Вот мой `docker-compose.yml`

```js
version: '3'

services: 

  #web services (php and extentions)
  web:  
    # path to Dockerfile for web
    build: ./web
    # for rights in apache
    environment: 
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
    volumes: 
      # path to application on local machine : path to application in container
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
    # app files in container is here
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}

  # databases
  db:
    image: mariadb
    # restart container if an error occurs
    restart: always
    # sync db on local machine and in container
    volumes: 
      - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql
    # mysql password for root user
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456

  # adminer for control database
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    # restart container if an error occurs
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6080:8080

  # install composer
  composer:
    image: composer:2.2
    volumes: 
      # to composer has access to the app files
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}/server:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}/server
    # workdir where scripts run
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}/server
    # install composer dependencies
    command: composer install
```

А вот содержание web:

```js
FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    # extension for mysql pdo
    pdo_mysql \
    # for laravel work
    && a2enmod \
    rewrite \
    docker-php-ext-install webonyx/graphql-php
```

Comment: скорее всего между `rewrite` и `docker-php-ext-install webonyx/graphql-php` должно быть `&&` т.к. это разные команды или вообще объединить две команды `docker-php-ext-install` в одну

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webonyx/graphql-php  не является расширением PHP и не может быть установлено при помощи docker-php-ext-install. Установите его [через композер](https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php#installation) как указано в документации.